# How to build a function to return the minimum distance to [-1,0,1]?

Tags: r

I have a real vector in the interval (-1,1), for example:

```
v = [ 0.999 0.0003 0.34 -0,95 0.63 -0.0001 0.82]
```

I want to build a function `fmindistance()` in R to return a vector of the indexes of all the elements of the vector `v` such as the distances from these elements to -1 or 0 or 1 are the minimum.

```
fmindistance <- function(vector, k){

......code ........

}
```

For example:

```
 v = [ 0.999 0.0003 0.34 -0,95 0.63 -0.0001 0.82] and k = 3, so:
```

Result = `[ 1 2 6]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, this function should work

```
v<- c(0.999, 0.0003, 0.34, -0.95, 0.63, -0.0001, 0.82)

fmindistance <- function(x, targets=c(-1,0,1), k=3) {
    r<- order(sapply(x, function(z) min(abs(z - targets))))
    sort(r[1:k])
}
fmindistance(v)

#[1] 1 2 6
```

This will find the closest points to any one of the targets. It will return the three closest in index order.

Comment: this matches the OP's desired results but doesn't seem to match the statement of their problem ...

Comment: @BenBolker To get those results, i interpreted as the minimum distances from any one of those points, not the minimum distance from each of those points. I had something that looked very much like your answer at first but i think this is another reasonable interpretation of the request.

Comment: OK, in hindsight (but `k` is never actually defined in their question ...)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you could save some typing with `order(sapply(x, function(z) min(abs(z - targets))))`?

Comment: Yes @alexis_laz, you're right. It would have been smarter to swap around my sapply arguments. Either you can post as a solution or I can update mine.

Comment: I guess it's the same concept eitherway; better to just update yours

Answer (score 1):

```
v <- c(0.999,0.0003,0.34,-0.95,0.63,-0.0001,0.82)
ff <- function(x) {
    sapply(c(1,0,-1),
           function(y) which.min(abs(x-y)))
}
ff(v)
## [1] 1 6 4
```

This does not match your suggested solution, but seems to be correct to me!  If you really want `(1 2 6)` as the solution, you should explain the logic a bit more carefully ...

Comment: You beat me for a few seconds, I was writing the same! And I get the same results too :)

Comment: ohh.... actually looking at MrFlick's solution I think the OP solution may be correct. Maybe he wants the first 3 elements that are closest to either of the limits... we should wait for his confirmation... +1 anyway for the use of which.min :)